# Gunicorn Nginx Permission denied while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, selinux

Setting up a django site with gunicorn & nginx

gunicorn settings for projects :

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=username
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/my_project
ExecStart=/home/username/my_project/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/username/my_project/my_project.sock my_project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Nginx configuration file for project:

```
user nginx;

server {
    listen       80;
        server_name  192.168.66.106;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static {
            alias /home/username/my_project;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/my_project/my_project.sock;
       }
    }
```

I have these permission of my projects

```
drwxrwxr-x. 5 username nginx 4.0K Apr  4 10:20 modulo1
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 username nginx  823 Apr  4 10:13 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x. 4 username nginx 4.0K Apr  4 10:20 modulo2
drwxrwxr-x. 2 username nginx  249 Apr  4 10:29 my_project
srwxrwxrwx. 1 username nginx    0 Apr  4 10:47 my_project.sock
-rw-rw-r--. 1 username nginx  565 Apr  4 10:13 README.md
-rw-rw-r--. 1 username nginx  228 Apr  4 10:14 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x. 5 username nginx   38 Apr  4 10:13 static
drwxrwxr-x. 3 username nginx   88 Apr  4 10:14 templates
```

this is a log error from /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2018/04/04 10:54:03 [crit] 14238#0: *4 connect() to unix:/home/username/my_project/my_project.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream client: 192.168.66.50, server: 192.168.66.106, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/username/my_project/my_project.sock:/", host: "192.168.66.106"
```

Comment: centos 7, anyway i resolve the issue with installing:                                  sudo yum install policycoreutils-python
sudo semanage permissive -a httpd_t

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i have a centos 7 OS, anyway i resolve the issue with installing:

```
sudo yum install policycoreutils-python 
sudo semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```

Comment: It saved me a lot of time. Thank you dear community.

Comment: for CentOS 8, the package name has been changed. sudo dnf install policycoreutils-python-utils

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to resolve the same issue between nginx and uwsgi in SELinux Centos 7 and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

To add on top of your answer, CentOS/RHEL based Linux operating systems has SELinux (**Security Enhanced Linux**) by ***default***.

> SELinux can be either in the enabled or disabled state. When disabled,
>   only DAC rules are used. When enabled, SELinux can run in one of the
>   following modes:
>
> - **Enforcing**: SELinux policy is enforced. SELinux denies access based on    SELinux policy rules. This is the **default**. In enforcing mode, if something is against the defined policy, the action will be both blocked and logged. ***Hence, the permission denied issue you were facing***
> - **Permissive**: SELinux policy is not enforced. SELinux does not deny    access, but denials are logged for actions that would have
>     been denied if running in enforcing mode.

*Note : Below operations are to be executed while being **root***

**Option 1**:

- Use the ***getenforce*** utility to view the current SELinux mode
- Use the ***setenforce*** utility to change between enforcing and permissive mode.

  - Use `setenforce 1` to enter enforcing mode. [**Default**]
  - Use `setenforce 0` to enter permissive mode

**Option 2**:
Create a policy using utils such as ***policycoreutils-python***

> policycoreutils-python provides utilities such as semanage,
>   audit2allow, audit2why, and chcat, for operating and managing SELinux.

**EDIT** :

- Usually create a policy specific as below(I used uwsgi sockets):

> policy_name.te

```
module <NAME_OF_THE_POLICY> 1.0;

require {
    type var_run_t;
    type httpd_t;
    type initrc_t;
    class sock_file write;
    class unix_stream_socket connectto;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t initrc_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t var_run_t:sock_file write;
```

and then Create pp module from te :

> checkmodule -M -m -o policy_name.mod /path/to/your/policy/policy_name.te

once we have the module policy_name.mod created from policy_name.te configurations, run the below command to create compiled SE Module

> semodule_package -m policy_name.mod -o policy_name.pp

Finally, install the compiles SE Module policy_name.pp using below command :

> semodule -i policy_name.pp